# Run .sh file from php Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, python, linux, apache2, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run a .sh file from within a php file in Apache2 html folder.
I have installed Apache2 and PHP on the Pi. 
I have given permission to www-data to execute the file.
The .sh file excutes from the terminal.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['led1'])) { 
    if($_GET['led1'] == 1) {
        echo "**RESPONSE**";
        echo "  ";
        exec('sh /home/pi/AlarmCode/StartAlarm.sh');
        echo "**POSITIVE**";
    } else {
        exec("gpio write 0 0");
    }
}

?>
```

I can call the web server and get a response from my pc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried `echo shell_exe`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `echo exec('sh /home/pi/AlarmCode/StartAlarm.sh')`. What it returns?

Comment: Hi DrKey, **RESPONSE** **POSITIVE** is returned. Have you any ideas ?? :)

Comment: Then your file runs successfully. So what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: when the StartAlarm.sh runs successfully the camera i have attached to the Pi should activate. StartAlarm.sh calls a script that connects to an arduino and activates the camera.

Comment: your logic is not testing if the `exec` was successful. It just automatically prints POSITIVE. Can you do something like `if exec('sh /home/pi/AlarmCode/StartAlarm.sh') { echo "Positive"} else { echo "Negative"}` ? (A PHP person will have to give you the precise syntax if my idea doesn't work). Good luck.